# Why Image moves up in slideshow after running once HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am currently trying to make a website home page with a slide show running in the middle using HTML,CSS and Javascript. I have completed the placement of the slide show but once the whole slide show runs(3 images) it moves up. Why is this happening and how could it fix it. Thanks for any help in advance. I have tried placing the images both inside of the html and outside and both ways it isn't working

```js
function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
div5 {
  width: 325 px;
  style="position: absolute;
 top: 0 px;
  left: 0 px;
}
```

```html
<div5 class="slideshow-container">
  <div5 class="mySlides fade">
    <div5 class="numbertext"></div5>
    <img src="picture1.jpg" style="width:50%">
    <div5 class="text"></div5>
  </div5>

  <div5 class="mySlides fade">
    <div5 class="numbertext"></div5>
    <img src="picture2.jpg" style="width:50%">
    <div5 class="text"></div5>
  </div5>

  <div5 class="mySlides fade">
    <div5 class="numbertext"></div5>
    <img src="picture3.jpg" style="width:50%">
    <div5 class="text"></div5>
  </div5>


  <div5 style="position: absolute; top:200px; left:500px" </div5>
```

Comment: First off... you need to wrap the javascript in a script tag. `<script type="text/javascript"> INSERT CODE HERE </script>`  EDIT: I see what you did, ignore comment.

Comment: How are you calling `showSlides()`? And what do you mean by moving up?

Comment: @blackandorangecat.      The images move up on the screen after the slideshow runs through once

Comment: `<div5>` is not a valid HTML5 element and `style="position:` is not a valid CSS property. Please fix those (i.e. replace with `div` and `position:`, respectively). Also, you can't space the unit (`325 px`) from the value on CSS. Change that to `325px`